# Missing required parameters for [Route: emps.show] [URI: emps/{emp}]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\crud1\resources\views\emps\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

This is my empcontroller.blade.php

```
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\employee  $employee
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(employee $employee)
    {
        $employees = employee::all();

        return view ('emps.show',compact('employees'))->with('i');

    }
```

this is my show.blade.php

```
@extends('emps.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
               <a href="{{route('emps.index')}}">Back</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-borderd table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Age:</th>
            <th>Mobile no:</th>
            <th>Departmetn:</th>
            <th>State:</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($employees as $employee)
    <tr>
        <td>{{++$i}}</td>
        <td>{{$employee->name}} </td>
        <td>{{$employee->age}}</td>
        <td>{{$employee->mobile}} </td>
        <td>{{$employee->department}}</td>
        <td>{{$employee->state}}</td>
     </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

and this is my route.web

```
Route::resource('emps', 'empcontroller');
```

this is my index.blade.php

```
<div class="pull-left">
<a href="{{route('emps.create')}}">Add New product</a>
<a href="{{route('emps.show')}}">show employees</a>
</div>
```

when i click on the  show employees throw this error
Missing required parameters for [Route: emps.show] [URI: emps/{emp}]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\crud1\resources\views\emps\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code :

```
<a href="{{route('emps.show')}}">show employees</a>
```

You have to pass a parameter an id of an employee to show just that employee.

like this :

```
<a href="{{route('emps.show', ['id'=>$someId])}}">show employees</a>
```

One more thing, in the show method you get all the emplyees and you return them, that is not what the show method should do, it's index method that returns all the employees the show method shows just one record

Another thing is about naming conventions the class name should start with upper case `Employee`